# Calculating the difference and summing up in separate column

Tags: r

I have many variables having many observations. I have one standard variable. Now, I want to calculate the difference between the standard and observed variables only when the observation is bigger than the standard and summing up all the differences as a separate variables. In addition, the names of the variables that are bigger than the standard in a separate column.

```
Names   Standard    Das Dss Tri Tet
Aa  32  42  21  45  34
Ab  23  25  43  43  32
Ac  43  34  23  32  23
Ad  23  24  33  12  23
Ae  14  24  12  20  24
Af  43  42  13  12  43
Ag  12  13  22  13  22
Ah  32  32  42  42  23
```

OUTPUT:

```
Names   Standard    Das Dss Tri Tet Difference  No_Difference   Names_Difference
Aa  32  42  21  45  34  15  3   Das, Tri, Tet
Ab  23  25  43  43  32  52  4   Das,Dss,Tri,Tet
Ac  43  34  23  32  23  0   0   NA
Ad  23  24  33  12  23  10  2   Das,Dss
Ae  14  24  12  20  24  26  4   Das,Tri,Tet
Af  43  42  13  12  43  0   0   NA
Ag  12  13  22  13  22  22  4   Das,Dss,Tri,Tet
Ah  32  32  42  42  23  20  2   Dss,Tri
```

Comment: Your output is incomplete, isn't? It is not clear if you sum only the positive difference?

Comment: @agstudy, Yes its something like that, row-wise, Observation-Standard=+ve, than sum all the +ve values. I hope now it is clear. In addition the names of the columns that have bigger observation than the respective standard values. So, that I could see at which site the observation is positive. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your data from above is stored in the object `df`. Then this should work

```
df2 <- do.call(rbind, apply(df[, -1], 1, function(z) {
        ind <- z[2:5] > z[1]
        return(cbind.data.frame(
                        Difference = sum(z[2:5][ind] - z[1]), 
                        No_Difference = sum(ind), 
                        Names_Difference = paste(colnames(df[3:6])[ind], 
                                collapse = ", ")
                ))
    }))

df <- cbind(df, df2)
df

  Names Standard Das Dss Tri Tet Difference No_Difference   Names_Difference
1    Aa       32  42  21  45  34         25             3      Das, Tri, Tet
2    Ab       23  25  43  43  32         51             4 Das, Dss, Tri, Tet
3    Ac       43  34  23  32  23          0             0                   
4    Ad       23  24  33  12  23         11             2           Das, Dss
5    Ae       14  24  12  20  24         26             3      Das, Tri, Tet
6    Af       43  42  13  12  43          0             0                   
7    Ag       12  13  22  13  22         22             4 Das, Dss, Tri, Tet
8    Ah       32  32  42  42  23         20             2           Dss, Tri
```

Altough this is not really elegant and it's not very robust to use integers to index columns, in case the ordering of your variables changes at some point

Comment: @ adibender thanks for your reply but it is not giving me the right output. Probably my question was not in right way. I need to calculate the difference row-wise. For each value of standard column compare to the observed columns (i.e. Das, Dss, Tri, Tet) and if observed value is bigger calculate the difference and sum all the differences of each row separately and make a new column with name "Difference" and in addition the names of those columns as well. Thanks

Comment: @maria raz: can u give an example for one row to calculate the difference, for example the first one?

Comment: I thought it would be `(42 - 32) + (45 - 32) + (34 - 32)` for the first row

Comment: @ adibender you are right for the first row it should be like that.. and difference should be 25. I just realized that in my example there is a mistake and the result is given as 15, that should have been 25. 
But yes you get the idea right. Sorry and Thanks for your help..

Comment: @mariariaz what exactly is wrong with my solution then? which row is wrong? I think you might have some mistakes in other rows too in your example...

Comment: @ adibender All of them are giving Nas... I checked and found that there should have been some values as in this case it should have been 25.

Comment: when I run it, I don't get `NA`s, see above

Comment: The output is absolutely right and exactly what I wanted. But still I am not sure where the mistake is. Thanks for your help at least the code is working and now I just have to check my data file. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21195/discussion-between-maria-riaz-and-adibender)

Answer (score 2):

To add only those values where standard val is less than obs, here's an easy way. My example is for a single row, so I'll use a vector.

```
> foo<- sample(10,10,replace=TRUE)
> foo
 [1]  7  5 10  8  8  7  4  1  8  2
> sum((foo[-1]-foo[1])*(foo[-1]>foo[1]))
 [1] 6
```

Someone else can do the name-collecting :-)